# ListView Control and Details

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, controls

I'm a bit confused by a few tutorials that I read about the ListView.

I have a ListView control and on the left hand side should be a name, and to the right of that name should be like another column with some more text in it. For example:

#### ListView:

```
jason     blah blah blah  
item2     more blahs  
item3     jupiter  
item4     uranus
```

How can this be done? Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Columns header collection to add the columns such as

- Column #1
- Column #2
- Column #3

then use the ListViewItem's collection to set the values of the columns such this

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("foo");
lvi.Add("bar");
lvi.Add("baz");
listview.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Now, you will have "foo", "bar" and "baz" respectively under the columns "Column #1", "Column #2" and "Column #3" respectively.

You will find the Column collection from within the Properties tool box for the listview. Be sure you set the view type to 'Details' to see this effect.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for that. In the 2 tutorials i read tonight, the code was so messy and there were comments scattered all over the place! Very confusing

Comment: ListViewItem (lvi) no longer contains method: "Add".

Comment: Use lvi.SubItems.Add("foobar");